# Eager Loading: Filter Laravel Posts by Categories

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I just discovered Eager Loading for the first time and I'm trying to optimize my code as much as possible.

My Posts model has a belongstomany relationship with a Category model:

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
```

In my Home view (home.blade.php), I'll like to display different sections based on post categories. Previously, I was doing multiple calls to the dabatase based on the categories I'll like in the sections so:

```
$featured = Post::with('categories', function($query) { 
    $query->where('name', '=', 'Featured'); }
)->get();

$breaking = Post::with('categories', function($query) { 
    $query->where('name', '=', 'Breaking'); }
)->get();

$special = Post::with('categories', function($query) { 
    $query->where('name', '=', 'Special'); }
)->get();

return view('home', compact('featured', 'breaking', 'special))
```

I've now discovered eager loading and I'll like to make this into one single call and then filter the categories.

```
$articles = Post::with(['categories'])->latest()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(40)->get();
```

This successfully returns 40 of my latest posts with categories, e.g:

```
{
"id": 43,
"title": "Sample nisi tempus nulla eleifend, eu iaculis felis aliquam",
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2021-04-17T16:17:48.000000Z",
"categories": [
  {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Featured",

  }
},
{
"id": 42,
"title": "Integer cursus nisi tempus nulla eleifend, eu iaculis felis aliquam",
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2021-04-17T16:17:48.000000Z",
"categories": [
  {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Featured",

  },
 {
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Breaking",

  }
},
 {
"id": 41,
"title": "Integer cursus nisi tempus nulla eleifend, eu iaculis felis aliquam",
"status": 1,
"created_at": "2021-04-17T16:17:48.000000Z",
"categories": [
  {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Special",

  }
}
],
```

But nothing returns I run:

```
$featured = $articles->where('categories.name', 'Featured');
$breaking = $articles->where('categories.name', 'Breaking');
$special = $articles->where('categories.name', 'special');
```

Please help: What is the right, eager-loading way of filtering the results without making multiple calls?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group each post by their categories, then start from you categories :

$categories = Category::with(['posts' => function($query){
$query->latest()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(40);
}])->get()->keyBy('name');

then you can access them with directly with:

```
$featured = $categories['Featured']->posts
$breaking = $categories['Breaking']->posts
$special = $categories['special']->posts
```

or in your blade template :

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<h2>{{ $category->name }}
<ul>
    @foreach($category->posts as $post)
      <li>{{ $post->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endforeach
```

If you really want to start from you Post model :

```
$featured = Post::whereHas('category', function($query){
    $query->where('name', '=', 'Featured');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to go about it with posts instead? I'm only getting 5 posts from each of the three categories and I'll like to display the rest of the posts as is.

Comment: I edited my answer if you really want to only get your posts, but I think you should start from your categories :)

Comment: Thanks again. I'm really trying not to have multiple calls to the database. Your updates answer is my current way of doing things and I'll like to improve on that :/

Comment: I want there to be one main query that returns 40 posts. Then I filter the returned posts by their categories.

Comment: My first solution would only do 2 queries, I don't get why that would be too much, it would be much more efficient that relying on collection to filter your results. You can achieve this by manually doing a join but the performance (and logic) for that would be aweful

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying. What would be the two queries?

Comment: First One would be the on for the Categories, the second one for the post, if you want to see what queries are done, you can use the laravel debug bar : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar  Or BEFORE your query : DB::enableQueryLog(); and AFTER your query : dd(DB::getQueryLog()); that will output the 2 queries done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231280/discussion-between-halesenchanted-and-mathieu-ferre).